# Why won't my program stop when I press enter

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, java.util.scanner

Trying to create a little app that creates randomized passwords for the fun of it, and I'm currently at the stage of trying to make a way to let my user stop the application. However, the loop keeps on going and won't get to my scanner, but for some reason this code would work, if I took out the use of the scanner and synchronized code block.

Anyway, what is wrong with this code?:

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner stopScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    final PasswordGenerator pG = new PasswordGenerator();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                pG.passwordGenerator();



            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

    t1.run();

    System.out.println("Press enter to stop!");

    stopScanner.nextLine();
    pG.shutDown();
    }
}

class PasswordGenerator{

private volatile static boolean running = true;
protected Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public void passwordGenerator() throws InterruptedException{
    synchronized(this){

        System.out.println("Select charecter set:");
        System.out.println(" 1: ABCDEF");
        System.out.println(" 2: GHIJKL");
        System.out.println(" 3: MNOPQR");
        System.out.println(" 4: TUVWXYZ");

        String charecters = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Select a password length");

        int number = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        if(number <= 6){
            System.out.println("Number cannot be smaller or equal to six!");
        } else {
            switch(charecters){
            case "1":
                while(running == true){
                    System.out.println("placeholder");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                break;
            case "2":

                break;
            case "3":

                break;
            case "4":

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No valid set chosen!");
                break;
            } 
        }
    }

}

public void shutDown(){
    running = false;
}
}
```

Comment: because you have a statement that is an assignment that will always return true, you need to use == in your while loop

Comment: Bug one, `while(running = true){` should be `while(running){` **or** `while(running == true){`.  [Bug two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo).

Comment: that was a mishap I made when I was re-evaluting my code, whoops. However even when I change it to == or take the = out it still won't stop the loop

Comment: You should add an if statement in your while loop to break the loop if a condition makes running = to false or just a condition to break the loop.

Comment: You have two threads sharing the same scanner.

Comment: That's why you don't use boolean literals for comparison. Next time just do `if(condition)` or `if(!condition)`.

Comment: Tried a few suggestions here ( post was updated to signify this ) but it still isn't working

Comment: It's getting worse. Using two scanners on the same input stream? Do not do it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the boolean value not changing - the problem is that the code doesn't continue to my scanner so I can stop the program by pressing enter. edit: then what should I do Luke Lee, I cannot think of a solution ; i'm stumped

Comment: You need to decide which thread is responsible for getting the user's input. Why are you using multithreading anyway?

Comment: I tried to make a loop that could be stopped using a scanner without multi threading and it didn't work

Comment: `t1.run()` should be `t1.start()`.

Comment: Please confirm, do you want to show "Press Enter to Exit" along with the options? As answer to this question may change the code structure. @CarbonZonda

Answer (score -2):

Your `running` is volatile, and accessing volatile members is implicitly synchronized on the object containing it. Check this: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml

> Access to the (volatile) variable acts as though it is enclosed in a synchronized block, synchronized on itself

So, the lock of `pG` is acquired by the thread calling `passwordGenerator`. It never releases it. So, your `main` gets stuck trying to access `running` when it calls `shutDown`

The problem is not related to your scanner(s)

Comment: "as though", means access to `running` is not guarded by an explicit lock. Or an "implicit" one.

Comment: @LukeLee From the same page: "synchronization happens Whenever a volatile variable is accessed."

Comment: Well, it's not the same as `synchronized`. And Java definitely do not acquire a lock on `this` before accessing `volatile` members. From the same page, in the table. `volatile` do not block.